# laravel logout not working with custom middleware

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, logout

When I try to access the logout route, I get redirected to the /home route all the time.

My route (account.php) to the logout controller:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['account'],
    'as' => 'public.account.',
    'namespace' => 'Auth',
], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'conta'], function () {
        Route::post('logout', [
            'as' => 'logout',
            'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout',
        ]);
    });
});
```

Authenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware\Acl;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as BaseAuthenticate;

class Authenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $this->authenticate($request, $guards);

        if (! $guards) {
            $route = $request->route();
            $flag = $route->getAction('permission');
            if ($flag === null) {
                $flag = $route->getName();
            }

            $flag = preg_replace('/.create.store$/', '.create', $flag);
            $flag = preg_replace('/.edit.update$/', '.edit', $flag);

            if ($flag && ! $request->user()->hasAnyPermission((array)$flag)) {
                if ($request->expectsJson()) {
                    return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
                }

                return redirect()->route('dashboard.index');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('public.account.login');
        }
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareAliases = [
        ...
        'account' => \App\Http\Middleware\Acl\Authenticate::class,
];
```

My idea was to have this middleware for 1 type of user, and Auth with ACL for all other administrative users.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since the `account` middleware is to be applied only to a specific type of user you should apply the `account` middleware **before** the `auth` middleware. So, when a user accesses the `logout` route - they will be checked against the `account` middleware first, if they match they won't be redirected to the `/home` route.

```
Route::group([

    'as' => 'public.account.',
    'namespace' => 'Auth',

], function () {

    Route::middleware(['account'])->group(function () {

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'conta'], function () {
            
            Route::post('logout', [
                'as' => 'logout',
                'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout',
            ]);
            
        });

    });

    // Other routes
});
```